# C - How to convert wide char Japanese characters to UTF-8?

Tags: c, json, encoding, utf-8, cjson

Trying to convert Japanese characters stored in wide char to UTF-8, in order to store the value in a json file using cJSON library. First tried using `wcstombs_s` but apparently this does not support Japanese characters:

```
size_t len = wcslen(japanese[i].name) + 1;
char* japanese_char = malloc(len);
if (japanese_char == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
size_t sz;
wcstombs_s(&sz, japanese_char, len, japanese[i].name, _TRUNCATE);
```

Then, based on other answers but also in a successful conversion from json UTF-8 to wide char, tried the opposite function as follows, but the destination buffer `dest` contains only garbage characters:

```
size_t wcsChars = wcslen(japanese[i].name);
size_t sizeRequired = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
char* dest = calloc(sizeRequired, 1);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, dest, sizeRequired, NULL, NULL);
free(dest);
```

The wide char (`wchar_t`) I am trying to convert is `ササササササササササササササササ` stored in `japanese[i].name` (a `wchar_t*` in a struct). Objective is to use cJSON's `cJSON_CreateString` to save the value in a UTF-8 encoded json file.

**Question:** What is the proper way to convert Japanese from wchar_t to UTF-8 char in C (not C++)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wcstombs_s()` code is passing the wrong value to the `sizeInBytes` parameter:

> `sizeInBytes`
>
> The size in bytes of the **`mbstr`** buffer.

You are passing in the *character* count of `japanese[i].name`, not the allocated *byte* count of `japanese_char`.  They are not the same value.

Unicode codepoints are encoded in UTF-16 (what `wchar_t` strings are encoded as on Windows) using 2 or 4 bytes each, and in UTF-8 using 1-4 bytes each, depending on their value.  Unicode codepoints in the `U+0080..U+FFFF` range take up more bytes in UTF-8 than they do in UTF-16, so it is possible that your `japanese_char` buffer needs to actually be allocated larger than your `japanese[i].name` data.  Just like you can call `WideCharToMultiByte()` to determine the destination buffer size needed, you can do the same thing with `wcstombs_s()`.

```c
size_t len = 0;
wcstombs_s(&len, NULL, 0, japanese[i].name, _TRUNCATE);
if (len == 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char* japanese_char = malloc(len);
if (!japanese_char)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
wcstombs_s(&len, japanese_char, len, japanese[i].name, _TRUNCATE);
...
free(japanese_char);
```

---

Your `WideCharToMultiByte()` code is not null-terminating `dest` due to you passing an explicit size to the `cchWideChar` parameter.

> `cchWideChar`
>
> Size, in characters, of the string indicated by lpWideCharStr. Alternatively, this parameter can be set to -1 if the string is null-terminated. If cchWideChar is set to 0, the function fails.
>
> If this parameter is -1, the function processes the entire input string, including the terminating null character. Therefore, the resulting character string has a terminating null character, and the length returned by the function includes this character.
>
> **If this parameter is set to a positive integer, the function processes exactly the specified number of characters. If the provided size does not include a terminating null character, the resulting character string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character.**

`cJSON_CreateString()` expects a null-terminated `char*` string.  So you need to either:

- add +1 to the `num` parameter of `calloc()` to account for the missing null terminator.

```c
size_t wcsChars = wcslen(japanese[i].name);
size_t len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
char* japanese_char = malloc(len + 1);
if (!japanese_char)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, japanese_char, len, NULL, NULL);
japanese_char[len] = '\0';
...
free(japanese_char);
```

- add +1 to the return value of `wcslen()`, or set the `cchWideChar` parameter of `WideCharToMultiByte()` to -1, to include the null terminator in the output.

```c
size_t wcsChars = wcslen(japanese[i].name) + 1;
size_t len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (len == 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char* japanese_char = malloc(len);
if (!japanese_char)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, wcsChars, japanese_char, len, NULL, NULL);
...
free(japanese_char);
```

```c
size_t len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (len == 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char* japanese_char = malloc(len);
if (!japanese)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, japanese[i].name, -1, japanese_char, len, NULL, NULL);
...
free(dest);
```

Comment: It works (also I was forgetting to add `,s8` to VS watch window to see UTF8 encoded value, but it was wrong without your fix: I had `ササササササササササササササササ6Cfp`). Once again, thanks a lot for the detailed answer.